# how to perform the validation on django html form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

View

```
def Checkout(request):
    amount_str = request.POST.get('amount')
    amount = int(float(amount_str) * 100)
    cart = request.session.get('cart')
    tax = sum(i.get('tax', 0) for i in cart.values() if i)


    payment = client.order.create(
        {
            "amount": amount, 
            "currency": "INR",
            "payment_capture" : "1"
        }
    )
    
    order_id = payment['id']

    context = {
        'tax' : tax,
        'order_id' : order_id,
        'payment' : payment,
    }
    return render(request, 'checkout/checkout.html', context)
```

html

```
<div class="container">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'placeorder' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="checkbox-form mt-30">
                            <h3>Billing Details</h3>
                            <div class="row">
                                
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="checkout-form-list">
                                        <label>First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" value="{{user.first_name}}" name="first_name" placeholder="" readonly>
                                        <input type="text" value="{{order_id}}" name="order_id" placeholder="" hidden>
                                        <input type="text" value="{{payment}}" name="payment" placeholder="" hidden>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="checkout-form-list">
                                        <label>Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" value="{{user.last_name}}" name="last_name" placeholder="" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="checkout-form-list">
                                        <label>Address <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Street address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="checkout-form-list">
                                        <label>Postcode / Zip <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" required name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode / Zip">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
</form>
</div>
Not adding all the fields
```

this is my checkout page. if I click the continue button I want to perform the validation like all the fields are required. but in this case, I did not add any validation so I got the page error how can I add the validation in this code. i want to perform the validation using Django message

Comment: What do you mean by "page error"? Can you add more details so that we know what you are trying to solve?

Comment: in this case, first name and last name are autofill as per the login user, so the rest of the fields are address, district, Pincode, mobile, etc. So if I click the continue button without entering the corresponding field I got the error **ValueError at /cart/checkout/placeorder
Field 'postcode' expected a number but got ''.** so thats why i want to add the validation like all the fields are required

Comment: Thanks for the details. Can you also include the HTML for the 'postcode' field?

Comment: now i got it i add the required in my input fields

Comment: Adding `required` would make a field required https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required but if you need to bypass the validation or use a default value then you would need to handle that in your view.

Comment: how can I add the validation in my HTML forms using the Django message? can you please check the code i add the post code field

Answer (score 0):

I think In Django, you can perform form validation using Django's built-in form handling capabilities and display validation errors using Django messages.

Add validation to your HTML form, you should create a Django form that corresponds to the fields in your HTML form. Here's how you can do that:

Create a forms.py file in your app directory (if it doesn't exist already).

Define a Django form class in forms.py that represents the fields you want to validate.